# Rails Infinite Loop - Stack Level too Deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running into a `stack level too deep` and have an infinite loop, but I can't figure out why, so I'm hoping someone else can spot it.

I have this method in my Game model:

```
def self.record_win_or_tie(game_id)
  game = Game.find(game_id)

  if game.home_team_score > game.away_team_score 
    game.home_team_won = true
    game.save
  end

end
```

When I run it from the console for a game where the conditional is true (ie game.home_team_score is greater than game.away_team_score) if keeps running the same query over and over again.

```
SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` WHERE `games`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

If I run the code for a game_id where the conditional is false, the query looking for the game only happens once and there is no infinite loop.

*** UPDATE ***

I figured out that the problem was that I was calling the method from my GameObserver:

```
class GameObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(game)
    Game.record_win_or_tie(game.id)
  end
end
```

However, I don't know how to adjust my code.  The requirement is to automatically update either `game.home_team_won` or `game.away_team_won` after someone has updated `game.home_team_score` or `game.away_team_score`.

It seems like I can't use an observer to do this.

Comment: What method is reported in the error message that is being run over and over?  And pedantically, you don't have an infinite loop, but rather infinite recursion.

Comment: Could you also add your `find()` method?

Comment: When I run `Game.record_win_or_tie(game_id)` from the console, it shows the query for finding the game, it shows that it sets the `home_team_won = true`, and then it repeats the game find query repeatedly, and ends with `SystemStackError: stack level too deep Maybe IRB bug!`

Comment: I don't have anything special defined for Game.find, so it would work as it normally would.

Comment: Oh, I found the issue - it's because this is triggered from an observer using `after_save`.  Is there a way to automatically run this after the game record is updated?  The app works with someone updating the home_team_score or away_team_score and then it automatically updating the record after this.

Comment: By the way, why is this a class method rather than an instance method?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on where the code should go

Comment: can't you use before_save and not save it in your `.record_win_or_tie` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an instance variable to ensure it only gets saved once.  However, because this is a class method, it will not be thread safe.  Instead make this an instance method like so:

```
def record_win_or_tie
  return if @inside_callback
  @inside_callback = true

  if home_team_score > away_team_score 
    update_attributes(:home_team_won => true)
  end      
end
```

Now you can have your observer trigger the instance_method like this:

```
class GameObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :game

  def after_save(game)
    game.record_win_or_tie
  end
end
```

Note that you can also avoid all this if you perform this logic in a `before_save` callback (without actually saving inside the callback) instead of `after_save`:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  def record_win_or_tie
    self.home_team_won = true if home_team_score > away_team_score 
  end
end

class GameObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :game

  def before_save(game)
    game.record_win_or_tie
  end
end
```

Comment: That sounds like a better solution, but I don't quite understand how to change my code to do this.

Comment: Thanks Pinny.  I got the after_save to work, but for some reason the before_save never saved home_team_won although it did go into game.record_win_or_tie  (I added puts statements to see).  Is the before_save the best way?

Comment: @yellowreign: `before_save` is certainly better because you only go to the database once.  Can you post what code you are using to save the game that triggers the before_ or after_ callback?

Comment: Thanks @PinnyM.  I put the code in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/ryanchin/5112626

Comment: @yellowreign, from what you are posting, it appears that you are calling this method directly in your code (`game.record_win_or_tie`).  But this defeats the purpose of having a callback in the first place.  You should simply be calling `game.save` where you need to, and have the callback take care of setting `win_or_tie` automatically.

Comment: Note in the 2nd example, you'd need "self.home_team_won = true", otherwise it'd make a local variable (at least this was the case with rails 3)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that you have defined an after_save callback that calls Game.record_win_or_tie again? That would explain the infinite recursion.

Otherwise we'd need to see the entire Game model

Answer (score 0):

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  # def self.record_win_or_tie(game_id) # deprecated
end

class GameObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(game)
    if (game.home_team_score > game.away_team_score) && game.home_team_won != true
      game.home_team_won = true
      game.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason it has to be in an after_save, instead of saving the current instance and triggering the after save, or adding spurious instance variables, call update on the db directly.

```
if game.home_team_score > game.away_team_direct
  Game.update_all({:home_team_won => true}, :id => id)
end
# Check the syntax, as I wrote it off the top of my head
```

But personally, if possible I'd move it to a before_save as mentioned in another answer.